# Reference newest google sheet in specific drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently using code that pulls data from a sheet with the `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` command. I would like to be able to change it to recognize the newest Google sheet in a specific drive folder. Does app script support such a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Check out the detailed info here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/

Something like...

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
var files = folder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   if (new Date() - file.getLastUpdated() > 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
     file.setTrashed(true);
   }
```

Good Luck!